# Replace PlaceHolder View With other ViewControllers leads to Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code 1

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, exc-bad-access, uistoryboardsegue

hey guys created a custom segue tab bar, using this guys tutorial,

http://www.scott-sherwood.com/tutorial/ios-5-creating-a-custom-side-tabbar-using-storyboards-and-custom-segues/

after trying to figure out why why my app doesn't work, i realised that the technique i was using was about replacing the existing view with the linked ViewController as a subview.

////////////////////////////////////////// the over-written perform method as follows  /////////////////////////

```
-(void) perform  {

    ViewController *src = (ViewController *)[self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

    for (UIView *view in src.placeholderView.subviews ) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }


    src.currentViewController = dst;
    [src.placeholderView addSubview:dst.view]; }
```

////////////////////////////////////////////// /////////////////////// /////////////////////// ///////////////////////

now once i am on the linked ViewControllers i was hoping to add another link to another ViewController which would hold the Editing functions for the information each respective pervious ViewControllers. Now when i try to connect a the ViewControllers via any Segue the app crashes and give me a Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS. When i use NSZombie its give me this in the console,

[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7c3a4d20

no i understand what is happening in theory, the viewController is trying to ad the next one to an empty space (i think the entire placeHolder has been deleted thus giving the viewController nowhere to go) i think, i was wondering if anyone could help with this i mean i a have been looking everywhere for a solution but i keep getting the same error.

i even created a VieController class for the ProfileViewController.m/ProfileViewController.h in which i add

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ProfileEditSegue"]){
        ProfileViewController *cvc = (ProfileViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];


        [cvc.placeholderView addSubview:cvc.view];
    }
}
```

this to leads me to the same errors. I will be glad to send anyone my source files, the same error occurs when i do it on the supplied files from the tutorial.

PS. i am using this method so that i can have a vertical navigation bar, but i want to do it simply so i could also learn how one works and be able to use/develope it further.

any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasnt in those methods it was because the currentViewController instances was set to weak instead of strong